# Calculation of a sphere in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate the volume of a sphere, with floating points, but I couldn't quite understand the logic behind the exercise.

> Write a program that calculates and displays the volume of a sphere,
> providing the value of its radius (R). The formula for calculating
> volume is: (4/3) * pi * R3. Consider (assign) to pi the value 3.14159.

```
const PI = 3.14159;

let R = parseFloat(gets());


//TODO: Fill in the blanks with a possible solution to the challenge

print("VOLUME =          "  +          );
```

Comment: The logic is just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere#Enclosed_volume - basic maths. You're asked to translate the formula into the respective JavaScript expressions.

Comment: The line beginning with `const =` is yours, not part of the exercise, right?

Comment: @Dropout The code in your answer was still wrong - `parseFloat` doesn't take a second argument

Comment: @Bergi how do you even post that without saying how?

Comment: Is `R3` present in the assignment as you wrote it here or it is "R to the power of 3" and you didn't know how to write it? In programming, this is usually written as `R^3` or `R**3` or `pow(R, 3)`, depending on the language, but most developers understand all these notations.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining, I'm studying javascript for the first time and really this specific exercise, I can't do it.

@bergi I edited the code, to the original version.

Comment: @Dropout i didn't post a correction since figuring out the solution appears to be the meat of this exercise. So far, OP only seems to have trouble understanding the exercise, presenting the solution wouldn't help with that. If they have trouble with the syntax or "*how to do X in JS*", they should ask for that specifically.

Comment: I'm having difficulties converting the mathematical logic to the exercise.

Comment: JavaScript does not provide a `gets()` function. If you run the code in browser then you can use [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) to ask the user to enter a value. For Node.js there are functions in the [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/readline.html) internal module or you can get the value as a command line argument.

Comment: What is `gets()` ? Also look at [`Math.PI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI), [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) and how to [declare variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables#declaring_a_variable). Also read [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to see what it does and its arguments.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Which part of the mathematical logic precisely? Your attempt was quite close, apart from using `parseFloat` instead of `Math.pow`

Comment: @PauloRoberto actually you can just copy and paste the formula,, then correct `pi` to be uppercase and correct the `R3`.

Comment: @axiac, Gabriele: `gets()` is likely part of the learning environment that runs this code. Notice it's part of the assignment, so it likely works as-is

Comment: Reading a lot of the tips here, I solved it, I don't know if it's the best way, but I solved it.

const PI = 3.14159;

let R = parseFloat(gets());
var raio = parseFloat(R);

var volumeEsfera = (4/3) * PI * Math.pow(raio, 3);


print("VOLUME =          "  +    volumeEsfera.toFixed(3) );

Comment: @PauloRoberto, `var raio = parseFloat(R); ` is redundant. Just use `R` wherever you use `raio`. It is already a float number. The rest looks good.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Thanks for the help, I'll refactor.

Answer (score 2):

You should try by yourself, but here is the solution and explanation.

If you are using javascript on the browser:

```
let radius = parseFloat(prompt("Enter value for radius: "));
let volume = 4/3 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
console.log("The volume is: ", volume);
```

We are requesting the user input with [prompt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) and assigning it to radius variable. We calculate the volume with the equation  `v = 4/3 πr³`, [Math.PI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/PI) represents the number PI and [Math.pow()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) calculates the given base (*this case, radius*) taken to the power of the given exponent. Last step is to print the result to the output, which is done with [console.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log)

Answer (score 1):

Reading a lot of the tips here, I solved it, I don't know if it's the best way, but I solved it.

```
const PI = 3.14159;

let R = parseFloat(gets());
var raio = parseFloat(R);

var volumeEsfera = (4/3) * PI * Math.pow(raio, 3);


print("VOLUME =          "  +    volumeEsfera.toFixed(3) );
```